# How to generate Im, Re octave filter

Tags: vb.net, filter, fft

I have function, which convert result from FFT to octave band (or 1/n - octave):

```
Function OctaveFilter(LowFreq, HighFreq, Im, Re) 'For amplitude
  Dim i, j, SortedData(), F_From(), F_To()
  Redim SortedData(Bins * n), F_From(Bins * n), F_To(Bins * n)

  Dim p
  For i = 1 To Bins * n
    F_To(i) = Int(HighFreq(i) / df)
    F_From(i) = Int(LowFreq(i) / df)
    if (F_From(i) = 0) Then F_From(i) = 1 ' We cannot start from index 0
  Next

  For i = 1 To Bins * n
    SortedData(i) = 0
    For j = F_From(i) To F_To(i)
      If (Length >= j) Then
        SortedData(i) = SortedData(i) + Im(j)^2 + Re(j)^2
      End If
    Next
  Next

  SortInBins = sqrt(SortedData)
End Function
```

For example this FFT:
[Amplitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOlkh.jpg)

converts to this 1/3- octave bands:

[1/3 - octave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9rat.jpg)

But from FFT I also have Re and Im part. I want to convert these parts to octave band too. Is it the same function? How can I convert this [Im part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vz1q.jpg) imaginary part to similar result (1/3 - octave) ?

Comment: I suppose you could similarly compute an average imaginary & real part over each 1/3 octave band, but I can't say whether that's what you'd need. Unlike the squared-magnitude which has an obvious meaningful interpretation as the band's energy, I can't quite see a useful interpretation for the average imaginary & real parts over the band. What kind of application did you have in mind?

Comment: I want to see how it Re, Im parts changes during the time. And for this I need 1/n-octave bands.

Comment: Real & imaginary parts make sense in the context that they represent how the signal correlates with a sine/cosine at a given frequency, and you can see how that varies over time for that frequency. But over an entire 1/n-octave band, the relative phase of those reference sine/cosine would vary, so the real/imaginary part correspondence isn't trivial. Identifying exactly what you are trying to achieve with this would help in determining how it can be done.